# Drawing flow diagrams for object oriented systems

Tags: java, uml

I have developed a project using the Java language.

Is it right, conventionally, to include diagrams like Context Flow and Data Flow, Entity Relationship Diagram in my system? Are these diagrams used only in systems which are developed in structured programming?

Should I stick to only UML based diagrams if my system is an object oriented system?

Though this may seem a silly question, nevertheless it is important while documenting a project following strict software engineering conventions.

Comment: I would use whatever diagram schema your company recommends and whatever your colleagues are most familiar with.

Comment: True.But not if there stands a review team to check whether every piece of document is in accordance with the universal standards prescribed.

Comment: I guess my point is, this would be a better question for your colleagues than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does this belong in [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) rather than SO?

Answer (score 1):

UML 2.2 diagrams are comprised of Structure diagrams and Behavior diagrams.  See this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language).

There are 14 diagram types in UML 2.2. I would steer towards UML. Is it possible to make your Context Flow or Data Flow an Interaction Overview Diagram? The Entity-Relationship diagram into a Class Diagram?

Java and UML can fit together very nicely. There are Eclipse plug-ins, for example, at https://stackoverflow.com/q/390438/509840.

Comment: Thanks so much. I initially wasnt aware that flow diagrams must be avoided in case of object oriented scenarios and went ahead developing CFD, DFD and ER diagrams.So would you suggest i convert my ERD to a complete class diagram if i wish to depict the entire table structure of my database to the user?

Comment: The conversion from ERD to UML Class diagram is really up to you and you should consider what would be most useful to your colleagues with a minimal fuss. If your DB has a built-in diagram generator, I would go the direction of fast & generate-changes-at-will. If not, I'd recommend you search on "eclipse database uml plugin" and see if these diagrams might be generated automatically. Save yourself a maintenance nightmare and use what's at hand.